# Gulp.js with foundation / compass

Tags: javascript, node.js, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, gulp

Has anyone successfully gotten Gulp-sass to work with foundation 4/5 (with compass preferably?)

The application is using foundation 4 successfully, without gulp, using `compass watch`. But I want to start using gulp to streamline my sass/coffee/minification compilation.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    util   = require('gulp-util'),
    sass   = require('gulp-sass'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee');

var paths = {
    scripts: {
        src:  'src/coffee/**/*.coffee',
        dest: 'public/javascripts'
    },
    styles: {
        src:  'src/sass/*.sass',
        dest: 'public/stylesheets'
    }
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.src)
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
   return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

This works great for the coffee script compilation, but fails at the commented line, when it comes to sass/compass.

```
[gulp] Using file path/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to path
[gulp] Running 'scripts'...
[gulp] Running 'sass'...
[gulp] Running 'watch'...
[gulp] Finished 'watch' in 15 ms
[gulp] [gulp-sass] source string:1: error: @import directive requires a url or quoted path
// Here is what's throwing me for a loop. I'm assuming that it has something to do with
// gulp-sass not utilizing the ruby gem's source files for zurb-foundation/compass
[gulp] Finished 'sass' in 115 ms
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' in 122 ms
[gulp] Running 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' in 11 μs
```

Is there a way around this, or is my best bet to upgrade from 4 to 5 and add the foundation files in my src/coffee, so it doesn't have to rely on looking in my `.rvm/../gems` folder??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [gulp-compass](https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass) instead of gulp-sass.

**EDIT**

Let me apologize for my poor answer first.

I tested gulp-compass by myself and it worked. I'm not sure about your Foundation setup but what I picked was *Using Foundation With Compass* on [Getting Started on SASS](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html).

The relevant part of my gulpfile.js is:

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src:  'scss/*.scss',
    dest: 'stylesheets'
  }
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: './config.rb',
      css: 'stylesheets',
      sass: 'scss'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});
```

The example above has a different directory structure from yours. So, your gulpfile.js would be:

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src:  'src/sass/*.sass',
    dest: 'public/stylesheets'
  }
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: './config.rb',
      css: 'stylesheets',
      sass: 'sass'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});
```

For the options for 'compass()', 'css' should be your 'css_dir' in your 'config.rb' and 'sass' for 'sass_dir' as described in [the README of gulp-compass](https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass).

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hahaha, that worked! Although it's at least twice as slow as compiling than normal compass watch, it does the trick. Thank you for your answer, and for improving the first part.